# Problem with url in Laragon. www.localhost/admin doesnt work but www.localhost/index.php/admin works fine

Tags: php

I am having trouble in my first steps with the model view controller.

I can't get the urls correctly.

if the url I enter is **http://localhost/admin/** I do not take it valid.
And it's the one I'm trying to capture.

However if I pass **http://localhost/index.php/admin** I capture it correctly.

I have read a lot and tried to fix it without success.

The rewrite module in httpd.conf is active.
And I have placed All and granted in the project directory.

my httpd.conf is

```
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so

DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/Atenea_MVC/public"
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/Atenea_MVC/public">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

my code is

```
$router -> get('/admin' , [PropiedadController::class , 'index']);
```

but this get only works if i pass the url http://localhost/index.php/admin

I am really very new to this.
I am learning and it is my first problem that I could not solve by doing research.

Thank you very much to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but please check .htaccess file in /public

Comment: Hello!. I tried with many examples of .htaccess but i don´t know how configure correctly

Comment: I don't know Laragon, so I think .htaccess in /public should contain
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`